# Right click on touchscreen for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, touchscreen

I got a new [Dell Inspiron 7373](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/inspiron-13-7373-2-in-1-laptop/inspiron-13-7373-setupspecifications/computer-model?guid=guid-e98b8d7d-d743-4b9d-9acc-31f9fa01dfba&lang=en-us) and everything is going fine, but I can't copy and paste files using the touchscreen because I can't send a "right click" action. In keyboard mode, I can do a two finger click on the touchpad to obtain the equivalent of a right-click, but my objective is to right-click using the touchscreen only.

Neither "touch-and-hold" or "short-tap + touch-and-hold" are working. Tested using xorg and wayland (as side note, gestures are smoother in wayland, but I can't drag and drop files).

Answer (score 1):

In touchscreen mode, do a short-tap + touch-and-hold. Just keep touching the screen for 2 or 3 seconds and what is called "right menu" should appear. This is the normal way to emulate a right click on any touchscreen.

Comment: I know I can make a right click with the touchpad, I am talking about the touchscreen. I can set the laptop in tablet mode and work without the touchpad and keyboard, but I am not able to set a right click using the touchscreen

Comment: No luck, no either "touch-and-hold" or "short-tap + touch-and-hold" are working. Tested using xorg and wayland (as side note, gestures are smoother in wayland, but I can't drag and drop files)

Answer (score 0):

I had same question - I was not able to get right click menu using touch screen. The solution which worked on my Lenovo Thinkpad was first select the file/folder with one finger (usual selection) and then tap again with two fingers with one finger on same file/folder. Same goes with opening context menu on empty folder space.

I have still not mastered it, but works more than 50% of efforts.